# Position of TD in TR

Tags: jquery

I have a look where I style a TD element based on matched content

```
$(".myTable td:contains('red')").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('myClass');
            var nth = $(this).index();
});
```

It works fine. Now I need to style TD in a row below. So I thought I could count the position of this TD and apply to the next TR

```
$(".myTable td:contains('red')").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('myClass');

    var tdNth= $(this).index();

    $(this).parent().next('tr').find('td:nth-child(tdNth)).addClass('myClass');
});
```

However it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: `$(this).parent().next('tr').find('td:nth-child(' + tdNth + ')').addClass('myClass')‌;`

Comment: You are missing a `)` after `.find()` %)P

Comment: @ArunPJohny IMHO, using string concatenation to build selectors is brittle and error prone.  Better to use `.eq()` and pass in a numeric value directly to find the right element.

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to "interpolate" a variable into a string constant.  That doesn't work.

Whilst you *could* use string concatenation to build the appropriate `:nth-child()` pseudo-selector, in my experience doing so is brittle and error prone so I try to avoid doing so wherever possible.

Instead, try:

```
$(this).parent().next('tr').children().eq(tdNth).addClass('myClass');
```

The above also avoids the "off-by-one" error your code would have had since `.index()` returns a zero-based offset but `nth-child` uses a one-based offset.

Comment: Except it only works when you use `eq(tdNth-1)` so off-by-one is still an issue when using `th` in row. `index()` returns position based on siblings, not based on siblings of same type, but `eq()` is index of matched elements.

Comment: @Anthony not sure what you're saying - the siblings of a `<td>` can only be more of the same or `<th>` elements, so only if the latter exist should there be any difference.

Comment: Right, and if the latter is the case, the index won't match

Comment: @Anthony so just account for that _if_ there are `<th>` elements in the row, and the OP doesn't say so.  You certainly can't say that mine _"only works when you use `eq(tdNth-1)`"_ because that's markup dependent!  In any event accounting for any such `<th>` elements is trivially done by just applying `.eq()` to _all_ children instead of `.children('td')`.  Your own method for that is utterly broken, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

If your table rows use `th` for first column, then the code:

```
var tdNth= $(this).index();
```

is going to be the index of the `td` including that `th`, so if it's the 3rd column and the 1st column is `th`, `tdNth` will be 3 which won't work with:

```
$(this).parent().next('tr').children('td').eq(tdNth).addClass('myClass');
```

because `eq(tdNth)` will select based on index of matching `td`s, which would be the 2nd in your row above, not 3rd. So instead, use:

```
var tdNth = $(this).parent().children('td').index($(this));
$(this).parent().next('tr').children('td').eq(tdNth).addClass('myClass');
```

This will ensure that index for both are based on index of `td`s and avoids off-by-one issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/55krupq2/3/

Comment: Your code only works by luck.  The `$(this).parent().index('td')` returns -1 and it then happens that `.eq()` takes that to mean the last column in the table which by chance happens to be the element you're attempting to modify.

Comment: Then why does it work for 2, 3, and 4 columms when i tested. And your solution only works because you assume only td siblings. The index matches "by luck" when the index within all siblings matches index for the selected element.

Comment: Test again.  That line cannot possibly work because as soon as you do `$(this).parent()` you've lost any context as to _which_ TD you're interested in.  That line actually says "what's the index of the `<td>` element in the jQuery object that's the parent `<tr>`?".  There isn't one, so it returns -1.

Comment: Updated. Now it finds the index of the `$(this)`within `children('td')` of parent of `$(this)`. So the `tdNth` will be actual index of selected within `td` elements of `tr`, which is what the manipulator is expecting.

Comment: That's better, but it's still over-complicated.  Simply removing `'td'` from `.children()` in my answer made it agnostic to any `th` elements without changing the OP's `var tdNth = $(this).index()`.   See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/kxaks4qt/